# Invading a friend while he is playing

Tags: watch-dogs

I would love to do a hack or trail mission against one of my friends.

**How can I invade a friends game?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Ubisoft Support's Twitter account](https://twitter.com/UbisoftSupport/status/472022700345806848) the invasion mode is random only.

> > @UbisoftSupport is there anyway you can hack your friends in watch dogs? I've been trying to figure out how to join friends games to hack
>
> @MyPizzaIsWarm No this multiplayer mode is random. [S]

Comment: Is it possible to be random matched with a friend? Or will it actively force out people from your friendslist?

Answer (score 2):

You can with the mobile app!  From the mobile app FAQ [here](http://blog.ubi.com/watch-dogs-ctos-mobile-companion-app-faq/):  Can I Play With Anyone I Want?

> Yep, you sure can. To start off, you’ll need to log in with your
>   Xbox Live, PlayStation 
>       Network or Uplay account. If you don’t have an account with any of the above, you can 
>       easily create a new one, using a free PSN or Xbox Live Silver account. (Uplay is always 
>       free.) Then, you simply enter your friend’s ID, and he’ll pop up in your system; if he’s 
>       available, you can invite him to play with you. Remember, though, you need to be logged 
>       in to an account on the same system as your friend in order to play with him.

The mobile game is pretty fun! I haven't played it myself, but I've had a friend trying to kill me while sitting on the couch next to me and we both had a blast!

Comment: +1: It's possible to run a ctOS mobile challenge with your friends, but only if: a) They're not on a mission, b) They accept your challenge.  It's not quite the same as "invading", but it's still good fun.